# Create/Update Azure App config through .NET 7 C# controller

Tags: c#, azure, .net-7.0, azure-app-configuration

I am trying to create (update if exists) Azure App Config values through .NET 7 C# controller.

The goal is basically send a key-value pair as json through my controller and let my backend process save that key-value pair to Azure App Config.

So the question is: can I send a key-value pair to Azure App Config through my C# code?

PS: I know it is possible through [Azure CLI and Importing through portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/howto-import-export-data?tabs=azure-portal) :)

Comment: Yes,It can be done from the Controller Action method.

Comment: Iam able to do it using the `SetConfigurationSetting`. Refer this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.data.appconfiguration.configurationclient.setconfigurationsetting?view=azure-dotnet#overloads) once.[Image](https://i.imgur.com/L37DQL5.png)

Comment: `a key-value pair as json through my controller`, can you share a sample json once.

Comment: I got the sol how to create appconfig from code.If you send the json format and from where you want to send.I will post an answer in detail.

Comment: it can be from anywhere, controller or a service. I just want to set a key-value pair. both are a string. like so `{"key":"value"}` . So my controller basically accepts a `Dictionary<string, string>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I send a key-value pair to Azure App Config through my c# code?

Yes, you can send a key-value from Controller Action Method and create a key-value pair in `Azure App Configuration`.

- As mentioned in the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.data.appconfiguration.configurationclient.setconfigurationsetting?view=azure-dotnet#overloads), I have used `SetConfigurationSetting` to create a Key-Value pair.

***My `appsettings.json` file:***

```cs
"AppConfig": "Endpoint=https://harshuappconfig.azconfig.io;Id=RoKQ;Secret=****************"
```

***My `Program.cs` file:***

```cs
var appConfig = builder.Configuration["AppConfig"];
builder.Services.AddAzureAppConfiguration();
```

***My `Controller` ActionMethod:***

```cs
  private readonly IConfiguration config;
  private readonly ConfigurationClient configClient;

public HomeController(IConfiguration myconfig, ILogger<HomeController> logger)
 {
     _logger = logger;
     config = myconfig;
     var connectionString = config["AppConfig"];

     configClient = new ConfigurationClient(connectionString);
 }
 public IActionResult Index()
 {
     var KVPair = JObject.Parse(@"{""Name"":""Harshitha"",""SurName"":""Veeramalla""}");
     foreach (var kv in KVPair)
     {

         Console.WriteLine($"Key '{kv.Key}' updated value '{kv.Value}' in Azure App Config.");
         var setting = new ConfigurationSetting(kv.Key, kv.Value.ToString());
         configClient.SetConfigurationSetting(setting);
     }
     return View();
 }
```

- Here I am sending the JSON object in a string.

***Output:***
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does this a duplicate proof? What happens if you send the same request twice? Do you end up with two configs or just the existing one gets updated?

Comment: For the same request it updates the value to the existing key.

Comment: I tried it from my end.For new request a new key-value will be created.For an existing key it updates the value.

Comment: Thank you Harshitha. I really appreciate your time and effort in helping me out.

Comment: Have you checked it from your end?

Comment: @NaveenSharma yes. I was going to do that when i got an answer to my question as a comment. Thank you for pointing it out again :)

Comment: yes, it works like a charm. you're a hero. Also rate the question if you don't mind :)